# IOU vs ROBIN metrics

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

Came across [this paper](https://robin.inrialpes.fr/robin_evaluation/downloads/ROBIN_metrics_v6.pdf) on ROBIN evaluation metrics. 
The metrics seem to be more informative than just IOU, so is there a reason why IOU is the preferred metric in most cases for object detection.

Also, are there any evaluations done as a comparison between the two?

Answer (score 0):

mean average precision is actually the preferred object detection metric. And it is common for authors to plot the AP curve. This curve is already sufficient to obtain all 4 of the detection metrics proposed in that challenge.